# "Linking" JComponents in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a few buttons and a few panels. Each button corresponds to a panel. I want to add an ActionListener to each button so that when the buttons are clicked, the visibility of the panels are toggled. However, inside the `ActionPerformed` method, I cannot get the JPanel. Here's basically what I have:

```
JFrame frame1=new JFrame();
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
frame1.add(panel);

JFrame frame2=new JFrame();
JButton btn=new JButton(panel.getName());
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        (somehow get panel).setVisible(false);      
    }
});
frame2.add(btn);
```

Comment: Why not use the panel reference variable.

Comment: Where exactly are you using this code? Why you can't get access to the panels?

Comment: And create mechanisms to join button to panel, such as a `Map<JButton, JPanel>`

Comment: @peeskillet What's a panel reference variable?

Comment: @Linksku `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` `panel` is the ref var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very good solution, but you can link swing components in following way

```
button.putClientProperty("panel", panel1);
//and somewhere in code
((JPanel)button.getClientProperty("panel")).setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to create a class that implements ActionListener. You could then pass in a reference to the parent JPanel and then refer to that in the actionPerformed method.

But if you really wanted to, you could use this convoluted one-liner.

```
((JComponent)e.getSource()).getParent().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

An AbstractAction could work well:

```
class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
  private JPanel panel;

  public ButtonAction(JPanel panel) {
    super(panel.getName());
    this.panel = panel;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    panel.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

elsewhere:

```
someContainer.add(new JButton(new ButtonAction(panel)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
e.getSource().getParent().setVisible(false);
```